# What is the difference between Storage and Databases in cloud services?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud

I am learning the GCP fundamental course, and I am confused about the difference between Storage and Databases in cloud services. Because data can also be considered a kind of file, can data also be stored in Storage?
Could you help explain the difference between these two concepts with an example? Thank you so much.

Comment: Structured and unstructured. You can put structured data in Storage and Database (Json -> Document, or CSV like -> Relational) and query them, thanks to a language (SQL stands for Standard Query Language). Unstructured (music, images, videos, zip archive, encrypted files,....) can be only stored in storage service. Of course, you can put the raw file as-is in a database, but you can't query it, and you are limited in term of size and performance.

Comment: As simple of a question as this sounds, the answer is not. Before the days of the cloud and "Data Lakes", the separation of storage and databases was well defined. Storage meant raw data without intelligence. Databases provided structure and computing abilities (query, sort, process, etc). Today, the line blurs with cloud services adding the ability to query cloud storage.

Comment: Both use storage devices such as disk drives, optical media, etc. Databases provide a higher level of organizing data into tables and columns. Think of it like a box of receipts (storage) versus a spreadsheet of income, expenses, deductions, etc (database).

Answer (score 1):

Storage is for file storage such as images and pdfs.

Database is basically a storage but it stores data records which can be queried using a query language.

Answer (score 1):

So in the storage, you can store files such as images. You can then store the link used to access that in a database. In a database, you store values such as users, usernames, and passwords. Imagine having a database with users, you would have both username and password text in the database and have another value with the image. The image is stored in the storage and in the database we just have the link as image value which sends you to the location of the stored image.